# how to display loader when response pending in angular 2?

Tags: angular

### below I used this loadImage function for load image,i want to display loading image when response pending.Here this._url_img my final response.

```
 loadImage()
    {
   this.isShowDocumentGif=false;
   return   this._organizations.getLogoUrldocumentmedia(this.documentlist).single().toPromise()
            .then(url => {
           this.isShowDocumentGif=false;

                this._user_img = url;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.isShowDocumentGif=false;
                console.log('Logo error', e);
                throw e;
            });
    }
```

Comment: You should compose an actual question

Comment: Use ng-show to show the  loader based on your logic

Comment: `ng-show = *ngIf` in angular2 @JijoCleetus

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
anyFunction(){
  this.isShowDocumentGif = true //variable to toggle your loader

  return this._organizations.getLogoUrldocumentmedia(this.documentlist).single().toPromise()
   .then(url => {
       this.isShowDocumentGif=false;
       this._user_img = url;
   })
   .catch(e => {
       this.isShowDocumentGif=false;
       console.log('Logo error', e);
       throw e;
   });
}
```

Comment: i already used but want to display loading image after than when response status pending.thanks